# Draw text method not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have a method to draw a string in a rect, but it is not working for some reason.

Here is the code:

```
- (void) drawString: (NSString*) s withFont: (UIFont*) font inRect: (CGRect) contextRect {

    CGFloat fontHeight = font.pointSize;
    CGFloat yOffset = (contextRect.size.height - fontHeight) / 2.0;

    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(0, yOffset, contextRect.size.width, fontHeight);

    [s drawInRect: textRect withFont: font lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeClip
        alignment: UITextAlignmentCenter]; }
```

Thank You!

Comment: You need to provide some useful information about what is wrong. For instance, crashlogs or a useful description of the issue rather than "it is not working". Also where do you call this method - inside a drawRect: method or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices here. You can implement "drawRect:" in some custom view you write, add a property to that view to set the string, and when you want the string updated tell the view to redisplay:

```
[myCustomView setNeedsDisplay];
```

If on the other hand you want to get the string into an image, you will use a different means to open a graphics context, draw the string into the context (a bitmap), then get an image created from the context.

Comment: Thats just crashing my app now.

Comment: Edit your question and add your UIView subclass code. Where is it crashing? You need retained properties on that view for font, string, etc - any value.